# What is 異 doing in the Cantonese translation of the movie title “Us”?

Tags: cantonese

I asked a similar question here:

[What is 剋 doing in the Cantonese translation of the movie title “Widows”?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/33409/4136)

---

The Cantonese title of the film [Us](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-mo/%E6%88%91%E5%80%91_(2019%E5%B9%B4%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1)) has been translated as:

> 香港譯《我們·異》

[Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-mo/%E6%88%91%E5%80%91_(2019%E5%B9%B4%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1)) also mentions that:

> 中國大陸、台灣譯《我們》

So, it seems that the Cantonese title is quite different here.

---

Guangzhouhua-Putonghua only mentions Mandarin definitions.

While Words.HK only gives the following:

> 語素
> 1
> 有分別；同其他嘢唔一樣
> different
>
> 異口同聲
> ji6 hau2 tung4 sing1
> saying something together; literally, different mouths but same voice
>
> 差異
> caa1 ji6
> difference
>
> 2
> 唔正常嘅
> unusual; extraordinary
>
> 異味
> ji6 mei6
> peculiar smell
>
> 異常
> ji6 soeng4
> abnormal

I'm still not getting the pun, though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

異 here short for '靈異' (supernatural) or 異形 (alien)

《我們·異》 means "Us - Supernatural" or "Us -Alien" ('alien' here might refer to alien from outer space, but it can also refer to the concept of 'non-native'. In the context of this movies, it implies "unearthly or supernatural being")